# Ingress - simple fanout configuration not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, docker-for-windows, microk8s

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. I installed microk8s 1.20.6 rev 2143 and experimenting with ingress. I must be missing something - but it doesn't work as I expect it to. I tracked the strange behavior down to the following configuration:

ingress.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ubuntu
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-ubuntu
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /nginx
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
```

nginx-service.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: http
    - port: 443
      name: https
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

Now,

```sh
curl my-ubuntu/                     # this returns Welcome page, as expected
curl my-ubuntu/nginx                # this returns Welcome page, as expected
curl my-ubuntu/bad-page.html        # this returns 404 Not Found, as expected
curl my-ubuntu/nginx/bad-page.html  # this returns Welcome page. WHY?
```

Any request under my-ubuntu/nginx/* returns Welcome page, even when the url is correct and should have returned different content. Did I configure something wrong?

I was able to reproduce the same strange behavior using Docker for Windows + WSL2 + Ubuntu + ingress installed using:

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.41.2/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

**EDIT**

nginx-deployment.yaml I used:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx
```

When I try `/nginx/` instead of `/nginx` like @HarshManvar suggested, I get this behavior:

```sh
curl my-ubuntu/                     # this returns Welcome page, as expected
curl my-ubuntu/bad-page.html        # this returns 404 Not Found, as expected
curl my-ubuntu/nginx                # this returns 404 Not Found
curl my-ubuntu/nginx/               # this returns Welcome page
curl my-ubuntu/nginx/bad-page.html  # this returns Welcome page
```

[Kubernetes Ingress documentation about Simple fanout](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout) also does use `/nginx` pattern but not working as described above.

Comment: try usign the path for Nginx route like `/nginx/` instead of `/nginx`.

Comment: @HarshManvar, that did not work. I'll add what I see to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/ explains how to use `rewrite-target` annotation. I was able to make it work with the following ingress.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ubuntu
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /nginx($|/.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
```

Each `path` defines regular expression with `( )`, which yields `$1`, `$2`, etc., aka. regex capture group variables. Now you put `rewrite-target` using those variables, and that will be the actual URL that is passed to the service's container that handles the request.

Maybe there is another way, but this is the only way I was able to make it work.